# ADOQuery SQL Syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement

Tags: sql, delphi

I keep getting an syntax error during runtime when this query is called.

```
adoquery1.Active := false;
adoquery1.SQL.Clear;
SQLQuery := 'INSERT INTO Comics ';
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + '(Name,Issue,Series,Volume,Poster,';
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + 'Desc,Writer,Artist,Read,Link,Extra) ';
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + 'VALUE('+ quotedstr(SeriesName+' '+IssueNumber);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(IssueNumber);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(SeriesName);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(VolumeNumber);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Poster);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Desc);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Writer);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Artist);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(haveRead);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(filelink);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Extra);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ')';
memo1.Text := SQLQuery;
adoquery1.SQL.Add(SQLQuery);
adoquery1.Active := true;
```

When i do the memo1.text = sqlquery, it looks to be ok, any suggestions?
this is what i get in the memo1.text..

```
INSERT INTO Comics (Name,Issue,Series,Volume,Poster,Desc,Writer,Artist,Read,Link,Extra VALUE('xmen 8','8','xmen','1','na','Some Description','BOBwriter','BOBArtist','Yes','C:\Comics\xmen8.cbr','Some Extra info')
```

Comment: This is just **so** wrong. Please do some searching on `parameterized queries` instead of doing all of the string  concatenation. You'll save yourself literally tons of trouble and make your code much cleaner, clearer, and safer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Desc` is a reserved word, so you should use `[Desc]` or enclose it in backticks (I don't know which database you're using).
More: I think it should be `VALUES(` and not `VALUE(`.

```
INSERT INTO Comics 
    (Name, Issue, Series, Volume, Poster, [Desc],
     Writer, Artist, [Read], Link, Extra) 
VALUES
    ('xmen 8', '8', 'xmen', '1', 'na', 'Some Description',
     'BOBwriter', 'BOBArtist', 'Yes', 'C:\Comics\xmen8.cbr','Some Extra info')
```

Comment: I tired using values and value,  Also changed the var DESC to Descrip,  Same errors..

Comment: @GlenMorse: did you try the query I wrote? I used brackets also for `Read`

Comment: @GlenMorse: you shouldn't change your var name, but your query!! Reserved word is inside your query...

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the **[Reserved Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)** `DESC` with `brackets`

```
adoquery1.Active := false;
adoquery1.SQL.Clear;
SQLQuery := 'INSERT INTO Comics ';
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + '(Name,Issue,Series,Volume,Poster,';
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + '[Desc],Writer,Artist,[Read],Link,Extra) ';
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + 'VALUES ('+ quotedstr(SeriesName+' '+IssueNumber);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(IssueNumber);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(SeriesName);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(VolumeNumber);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Poster);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Desc);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Writer);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Artist);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(haveRead);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(filelink);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ','+ quotedstr(Extra);
SQLQuery := SQLQuery + ')';
memo1.Text := SQLQuery;
adoquery1.SQL.Add(SQLQuery);
adoquery1.Active := true;
```

Answer (score 2):

use `Values` instead of `value`.
Desc and Read are reserved keywords, so enclose then in square brackets.
You forgot to keep closing parenthesis before `Values` keyword.

```
INSERT INTO Comics 
            (Name, 
             Issue, 
             Series, 
             Volume, 
             Poster, 
             [Desc], 
             Writer, 
             Artist, 
             [Read], 
             Link, 
             Extra) 
VALUES     ('xmen 8', 
            '8', 
            'xmen', 
            '1', 
            'na', 
            'Some Description', 
            'BOBwriter', 
            'BOBArtist', 
            'Yes', 
            'C:\Comics\xmen8.cbr', 
            'Some Extra info')
```